# Failed to get access token by using service principal while connecting to an ADLS location from ADF pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to deploy an ARM template for ADF using Azure DevOps CI/CD

The deployment was successful but while trying to test the linked services, I am not able to connect successfully.

The linked service is to get connected to the ADLS location under same subscription and the authentication method is using service principal and using key vault secret name to get the connection.

key vault is also under the same subscription and resource group.

While trying to connect the LS to ADLS location I am getting the below error.

```
Failed to get access token by using service principal. Error: invalid_client, Error Message: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.
Trace ID: 67d0e882-****-****-****-***6a0001
Correlation ID: 39051de7-****-****-****-****6402db04
Timestamp: 2020-11-** **:**:**Z Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: 67d0e882-****-****-****-***6a0001\r\nCorrelation ID: 39051de7-****-****-****-****6402db04\r\nTimestamp: 2020-11-** **:**:**Z","error_codes":[7000215],"timestamp":"2020-11-** **:**:**Z","trace_id":"67d0e882-****-****-****-***6a0001","correlation_id":"39051de7-****-****-****-****6402db04","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"}: Unknown error .
AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.
```

The linked services which is to connect clusters are working fine for which connection secrets are stored in the same key vault.

I was confused some secrets(for cluster connection) in the same key vault is working and few (for adls connection) are not working.

Had a check for the application under same principal id in Azure active directory and secret is valid till 2022.
[image]

Any Idea about the root cause of the error and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you added ADF to the Access Policy of the key vault and set the Key Permissions? Are your ADF and Key vault in the same region?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem before, you need to make sure that the client secret belongs to the application you are using, or you can also try to create a new client secret, it should work for you.

[image]